# Linked List delete deletes node before console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, prototype, this

So, I created a standard linked list class in js and it workds perfectly but this happens for example/.....

```
     var myRef = new LinkedList()  //let's say with vals 1->2->3   
     console.log(myRef) //2->3  They are both the same!!!! even though delete happens later in code!!!
     myRef.deleteFirst();

    console.log(myRef)  //2->3 They are both the Same!! 

    LinkedList.prototype.deleteFirst = function() {
       if (this.head.next == null) {
       return;
  }
  var dummy = this.head.next.next;
  var value = this.head.next.data;
  delete this.head.next;
  this.head.next = dummy;
  this.head.length -= 1;

  return value;

}
```

Comment: Related: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: Click on the `i` next to the console output and read the explanation there.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myRef));
```

This will print the stringify version of object. So instead of your object  will get the content of object otherwise because myRef is a pointer its content will change and the log show the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

The console will have a reference to the object, which will update when the object updates. You can do this:

```
console.log(jQuery.extend(true, {}, myRef));
```

which will create an independent copy of your object. That will allow you to examine the different states.

Comment: jQuery is not available in browsers by default.

Comment: true, you would need to include it (e.g. by putting this in your HTML: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`